# Transferring CSV files to PCs from Android devices

Tags: android, file-transfer, android-file

I have an application that generates csv files using the following method,

```
protected void makeCsvFileTrackLog() {
    final String CSV_SEPARATOR = ",";
    System.out.println("startMakeFile");
    Date T = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    String szDateTime = sdf.format(T);
    SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    String szDate = date.format(T);
    //creates /flightData directory on device if not created yet...
    File appDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "flightData");
    appDir.mkdir();
    //creates new file if needed for sampling date
    File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "flightData/" + szDate);
    exportDir.mkdir();

    try {
        File csvSandboxFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/flightData/" + szDate, "TracklogDB_" + szDateTime + ".csv");

        csvSandboxFile.createNewFile();
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(csvSandboxFile), "UTF-8"));

        DBAdapter msdb = new DBAdapter(getApplicationContext(), szDbName, null);
        db = msdb.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM trackLogDB", null);

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        ...
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("IOException", "exception in createNewFile() method");
    }
    System.out.println("endMakeFile");
}
```

This builds files no problem. However, problems occur when technicians and generic users try to offload data from devices to PCs. Most of our devices are running Android versions 7 or 8. PCs are current Linux or Win10. In order to offload data, the android device must be rebooted before being connected to the PC. Once connected, the user selects transfer files via USB on the Android device. If the PC is a Win10, they must wait for the Android unit to be properly detected by the Windows operating system. They must then browse to the directory on the device where the CSV file is located. However, the newly created CSV file is not "generally" visible in the directory until they refresh it. Sometimes a simple refresh works, at other times the directory must be closed and reopened.

**Question #1:** Is there anything that I can do on the Android application side to make my CSV files more discoverable?

**Question #2:** Is there anything that I can do to the windows or Linux boxes to help them find the files on the Android units?

Note: these CSVs do not contain "private" data.

Comment: I'm going to give you a suggestion despite your question, why don't you start an http server in your app, so people can dl the file from wifi (pc and phone must be connected to the same network of course) you can use Fetch library it's actually a download manager library but it also provides a http file server. Using this method they do not need usb cable connection and suffer from all the troubles of MTP

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Amim. Good one and makes sense. But our IT security people would lose their marbles if we requested access to "their" wifi.

Comment: `This builds files no problem.` Hard to believe as `File appDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageState(), "flightData");` can be no valid directory which you can easily check with appDir.exists() and the return value of mkdir() which you should only call if the directory does not exist yet.

Comment: In which directory do the files land according to the explorer on the pc? And in which directory according to a file manager on your Android device. Well i still can not believe that your code works..

Comment: Terrible code where you call `new File(Environment.getExternalStorageState()....` three times. You should do that only once. And it should be `getExternalStorageDirectory()` instead.